# How can I make design as shown in the attached image?

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

[image]

I want to design a screen like this. For displaying the grid items, I am using recycle view. But my concern is how to apply pagination and implement slide for next section of items when user swipe.

In case swipe is not possible, at least on click of the dots below the layout.

Comment: Are those grid items to be paginated vertically as well? If not, Use GridView along with ViewPager (for the dots and left right swipe).

Comment: @ShobhitPuri Thanks for the quick reply, I don't need vertical pagination. I will try with the approach that was mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You Should Use **GridLayoutManager** with `RecyclerView`

> **`GridLayoutManager`** is a `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` implementations that lays out items in a `grid`.
>
> just  set `GridLayoutManager`  to your  `recyclerView.setLayoutManager`

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.collection_recyclerview);
GridLayoutManager  gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(YourActivity.this, 2);
//                                                           --Context--,--No of Columns--


mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

tutorial demo of  [**`GridLayoutManager` with `RecyclerView`**](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Prem I will try with the above approach.

Comment: @Renadh welcome let me know if any query regarding this

Answer (score 1):

Create a new XML layout under layout and name it as grid_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >  

</GridView>
```

Create a new Class by right clicking on (Right Click) src ⇒ package folder ⇒ New ⇒ Class and name your class as ImageAdapter.java Extend your ImageAdapter.java class from BaseAdapter and fill it with following code.

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.example.dilip;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
            R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
            R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
            R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
            R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
            R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
            R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
            R.drawable.pic_15
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Open your main activity class as shown below.

```
AndroidGridLayoutActivity.java

    package com.example.dilip;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.GridView;

    public class AndroidGridLayoutActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

            // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First Step - Use [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Second Step - Inside Fragment you can use RecyclerView with GridLayout

Third - Finally you can use [CirlcePageIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

What you are looking is actually you can found in this block [GridView with Viewpager](http://shrikantsonarblogs.blogspot.in/)

You can also use **RecyclerView** instead of **GridView**